# Javascript function only works with input type radio, not with input type button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, octobercms

I have a function for AJAX pagination that only works with certain inputs (radio, checkbox, select) but I want it to use with input type button. This is my html:

```
{{ form_ajax('onFilterPieces', { update: { 'pieces/pieces': '#partialPieces' } }) }}
        <div id ="PiecesFilter"> 
            <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    {% for i in 1..pages %} 
                        <li class="page-item">                               
                           <input type="radio" name="Filter[page]" value="{{i}}">
                        </li>                                   
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </nav>               
        </div>  
    {{ form_close() }}
```

This is my JS:

```
(function($) {
    $('#PiecesFilter').on('click', 'input', function(){
      var $form = $(this).closest('form');
      $form.request();
    });
  })(jQuery);
```

I'm using OctoberCMS, that is why I have the twig syntax. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is it doing wrong? Have you tried putting a `console.log()` call in the function to see if it's running?

Comment: this is jquery, but not javascript

Comment: october `Ajax` api is using `serialize()` and it seems its not including button types, so you need to check alternative